# Why awk understand FS="*" but not for FS="-*-"?

Tags: awk, regular-expression, quoting

I got a test file, its content is:

```
a -*- b
```

I used `awk 'BEGIN {FS="*"} {print $2}' test`, it prints out

```
- b
```

Correct! But when I use `awk 'BEGIN {FS="-*-"} {print $2}' test`, I got:

```
*
```

I know that `FS` support regex, so I added `\` before `*`, I did `awk 'BEGIN {FS="-\*-"} {print $2}' test`
, still, I got:

```
*
```

Luckily, I got a blog write by myself half a year ago. Which mentioned I should use
`awk 'BEGIN {FS="-[*]-"} {print $2}' test` in this case. Thus I got:

```
 b
```

Correct again!

But I was really confusing why FS can understand `*`, can't understand `-*-` and `-\*-`, and finally can understand the `-[*]-`.

What's the mechanism in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `FS` is longer than a single character, it is treated as a regular expression.  An `FS` of just `*` is seen as a fixed string, but an `FS` of `-*-` is a regular expression, and `-*-` is equivalent to `-+` (one or more `-`). So you need to make `*` be considered as a regular character. `-\*-` and `-[*]-` can both do this. However, the string for `FS` is parsed *twice* - once when you're assigning it, and once for splitting on `FS`. That's why `\`-escaped characters need to have the `\` escaped as well.

```
$ awk -F '-\\*-' '{print $2,FS}' test.txt
 b -\*-
$ awk -F '-\*-' '{print $2,FS}' test.txt
awk: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'
* -*-
```

Comment: Why `-*-` is equivalent to `-+-`?

Comment: @cuonglm: It isn't, but that's not what muru said. He said that `-*-` is equivalent to `-+` but then he followed that with a '-' outside the backticks, which lead to your confusion.

Comment: So FS='ax\\*' and FS='ax*' has no difference?

Comment: @PM2Ring: The same question, why `-*-` is equivalent to `-+`?

Comment: @cuonglm `-*` means 0 or any `-`, `-` means one fixed `-`. `-*-` means 0 or any `-` plus one fixed `-`. `-+` means one or any `-`. They are different in order to create the `-`. But as all `-` are identical to us, these two command are equivalent.

Comment: @cuonglm `-*-` and `-+-` are not equivalent. The latter needs at least two `-`, the former at least one. It might simpler if you see `+` for what it is: syntactic sugar for `<exp><exp>*`.

Comment: @cuonglm: `*` means zero or more copies of the preceding pattern, `+` means one or more copies of the preceding pattern. So `-*` will match the empty string, and `-*-` needs there to be at least one `-` in the string to match, which makes it equivalent to `-+`

Comment: @Zen, oh I see the confusion. Edited to use brackets instead of hyphens.

Comment: @zen: There's no difference between `FS='ax\*'` and `FS='ax*'` because `\*` is treated as `*`, but awk will print a warning: `escape sequence '\*' treated as plain '*'`. If you want to put a literal `*` into the FS you need to use double backslash,eg `FS='ax\\*'` will split on `ax*`. I'll put some examples into an answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring: They're not equivalent. I know what they are meaning.

Answer (score 3):

A key point in muru's answer is that to get a backslash into the `FS` regex you need to write double backslash `\\`. That's because backslash is used as an escape character at two different levels.

A single backslash in a string will be treated as escaping the following character, so we need to escape the backslash itself so that we get a single backslash in the regex. And then *that* backslash will escape the following character within the regex.

As I said in a comment, there's no difference between `FS='ax\*'` and `FS='ax*'` because `\*` is treated as `*`, but awk will print a warning to that effect. If you want to put a literal `*` into the `FS` you need to use double backslash, eg `FS='ax\\*'` will split on `ax*`.

Maybe some examples will make all this a bit clearer.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

s='123abcd
123axbcd
123axxbcd
123ax*bcd
123ax**bcd'

printf "%s\n\n" "$s"

awk -F 'ax*' 'BEGIN{printf "FS=[%s]\n", FS};{printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' <<< "$s"
echo

awk 'BEGIN{FS="ax*"; printf "FS=[%s]\n", FS};{printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' <<< "$s"
echo


awk -F 'ax\*' 'BEGIN{printf "FS=[%s]\n", FS};{printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' <<< "$s"
echo

awk 'BEGIN{FS="ax\*"; printf "FS=[%s]\n", FS};{printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' <<< "$s"
echo


awk -F 'ax\\*' 'BEGIN{printf "FS=[%s]\n", FS};{printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' <<< "$s"
echo

awk 'BEGIN{FS="ax\\*"; printf "FS=[%s]\n", FS};{printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' <<< "$s"
echo
```

**output**

```
123abcd
123axbcd
123axxbcd
123ax*bcd
123ax**bcd

FS=[ax*]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [*bcd]
[123] [**bcd]

FS=[ax*]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [*bcd]
[123] [**bcd]

awk: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'
FS=[ax*]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [*bcd]
[123] [**bcd]

awk: warning: escape sequence `\*' treated as plain `*'
FS=[ax*]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [bcd]
[123] [*bcd]
[123] [**bcd]

FS=[ax\*]
[123abcd] []
[123axbcd] []
[123axxbcd] []
[123] [bcd]
[123] [*bcd]

FS=[ax\*]
[123abcd] []
[123axbcd] []
[123axxbcd] []
[123] [bcd]
[123] [*bcd]
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `"` delimiter, you need to escape the backslash one mre time.

```
$ echo 'a -*- b' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="-\\*-"} {print $2}'
 b
```

Since we are passing a regex to the FS variable, `\\` within the double quotes is parsed as single backslash and then it apply the resultant regex against the input string.

Comment: What's the logic of escape two times?